# Scala: SBT Builder crashed while compiling

Tags: java, eclipse, scala

I am trying to run a framework that has programs in Java and Scala. I get the following error on the Problems tab:

```
Error in Scala compiler: scala.reflect.internal.Types$PolyType cannot be cast to scala.reflect.internal.Types$OverloadedType

SBT builder crashed while compiling. The error message is 'scala.reflect.internal.Types$PolyType cannot be cast to scala.reflect.internal.Types$OverloadedType'.
```

Here is a screenshot of the error message: [Scala error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xu7k1.png)

Further, at the first line of one of the Scala programs, that says ‘package abc.def.gh’, I see this error message

```
Presentation compiler crashed while type checking this file: java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.reflect.internal.Types$PolyType cannot be cast to scala.reflect.internal.Types$OverloadedType
```

I tried both the Eclipse Luna & Mars IDEs, and get the same error message with both.

I am a newbie here. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please, post your buid.sbt file.

Comment: Hi Onilton, Thanks for stopping here! I don't have a build.sbt file, but I do have pom.xml file. Will that help? Do I need 'build.sbt'? I am sorry if this sounds naive, I am just a beginner.

Comment: Yes, please provide your pom.xml. Actually providing the name of the framework and the folder structure of your project would definitely help.